# How to send actor a tell message when a URL is accessed?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to connect the Akka HTTP with the Actors. I have a simple actor which receives "hello" and sends back "Hello world"

```
class TestActor extends Actor{
  def receive={
    case "hello"=>{
      sender!"Hello World"
    }
  }
}
```

I have defined the below route:

```
object Main extends App{

  val route1: Route =
    get {
      path("hello") {
        complete {
          "This is hello"
        }
      }
    }

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("h")
  Http().bindAndHandle(route1, "localhost", 8185)
}
```

I want to send a tell message to the TestActor when /hello is accessed in the URL and display the message "Hello World" as a response. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Option 1 is to use the "Ask" pattern. You can "ask" the actor like below. "Ask" returns a future which you can map over and do other operations. You can also complete the request with the future. The caveat here is that it requires a timeout. You have to configure a timeout for this to work which can become tedious to maintain in a larger project.

```
implicit val timeout: Timeout = 2 seconds
val responseFuture = (actor ? message).mapTo[String] // This will return a Future[String]
complete(responseFuture)
```

Option 2 is to use "Tell" pattern. This is much preferred over "ask" pattern. You can read about this [here](http://techblog.net-a-porter.com/2013/12/ask-tell-and-per-request-actors/). You need to pass the request context to the new actor and complete the request with that new actor. You will do something like below.

```
val testActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(classOf[TestActor], reqContext), "test-actor")
```

And in the testActor, you will complete the request. You can see [here](https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/spray-actor-per-request) and [here](https://markatta.com/codemonkey/blog/2016/08/03/actor-per-request-with-akka-http/) to get more information on this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 - Create the Actor Instance.

Step 2 - Get a reference to it.

Step 3 - Send it the message

```
class TestActor extends Actor{
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => {
      sender() ! "Hello World"
    }
  }
}

object TestActor {
  def props: Props = Props(classOf[TestActor])
}
```

Now...

```
import akka.pattern.ask

object Main extends App{

  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("actor-system")

  implicit val implicitActorSystem = actorSystem
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  // actually create the actor
  val testActor = actorSystem.actorOf(TestActor.props, "test-actor")

  val route1: Route =
    get {
      path("hello") {
        // get actor's reference using selection
        val testActorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection("/user/test-actor")
        // now send using selection
        val responseFuture = testActorSelection ? "hello"

        // or send using the "val testActor" reference which we already have
        val responseFuture = testActor ? "hello"

        onComplete(responseFuture) {
          case Success(message) => complete(message)
          case Failure(ex) => complete(ex.message)
        }
      }
    }

  Http().bindAndHandle(route1, "localhost", 8185)
}
```

Comment: I have modified the code and my requirement slightly. The actor is sending back the message instead of printing it. This message needs to be displayed as a response.

Comment: But I dont want to do it with ask. I want it to be tell.